Show / hide div using checkbox and addEventListener click event
EDIT: My issue is likely this, Text shows then disappears on page reload; javascript onclick event
The following javascript works but not in my application as a product filter. In my case, clicking the checkbox displays the div but unchecking does not hide the div. Applying, onclick event to the checkbox is also not doable. Is it possible to have two addEventlistener 'click' events, one for opening and one for closing?


const check = document.getElementById("checkbox-id");
if (check) {
  check.addEventListener('click', event => {
    this.event = event;
    if (check.checked) {
      document.getElementById("showDiv").style.display = "block";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("showDiv").style.display = "none";
    }
  });
}
#showDiv {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #252525;
  color: #ffffff;
}
<form>
  <input class="input" type="checkbox" id="checkbox-id">
</form>
<div id="showDiv">Show / hide</div>



I have tried the following (and others) but I have not been able to hide the box after being revealed. Just know, the click event is the only way that has produced a result.  Happy to provide any other info if needed. TY
const general   = document.getElementById("checkbox-id");
const checkOpen = () => {
  document.getElementById("showDiv").style.display = "block";
}
const checkClosed = () => {
  document.getElementById("showDiv").style.display = "none";
}
if (element) {
  element.addEventListener('click', event => {
    this.event = event;
    checkOpen();
    checkClosed();
  });
}


In my case, clicking the checkbox displays the div but unchecking does not hide the div, you're snippet does not reflect this statement. You can have ONE click event that simply toggles a CSS class for display.

Your snippet hides the div when the checkbox is not checked and shows it when it is. So please could you explain what else you want to happen. Also, why use JS for this instead of just CSS?

Lets pretend in my application, unchecking the box does not hide the div. Is there an alternative, such as multiple addEventlistener click events that can do the same thing? TY

Thanks Dale, I provided my attempt, (JS after the snippet) but this does not work. Maybe there is syntax I'm overlooking. This is why I'm here. For help.

I think we are getting a bit confused! You've provided a snippet which seems to do what is required, but you say that in your application it doesn't work. Therefore there must be more context which is making it not work and we can't guess what that is so at the moment we cannot help.

You don't need JavaScript for this. In your CSS you can use either the next-sibling (used in the example) or the subsequent-sibling combinator to show or hide the element.
In the example I also use the :has() pseudo-class to find the input element, because the two combinators need to be use on elements that are siblings (on the same level in the DOM tree).


#showDiv {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #252525;
  color: #ffffff;
}

form.showhide:has(input)+div {
  display: none;
}

form.showhide:has(input:checked)+div {
  display: block;
}
<form class="showhide">
  <input type="checkbox">
</form>
<div id="showDiv">Show / hide</div>




Thank you for taking the time look into my issue and with little to go on. Unfortunately, the CSS gives me an "Expected RPAREN." error. I have pseudo solved this by adding a close button to the div.

Here's the corrected solution to make your code work as expected. The issue in your code lies in trying to invoke both checkOpen and checkClosed on the same event without conditionally executing one based on the checkbox state.
Use the following code to correctly toggle the visibility of the div:
Solution:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Checkbox Toggle</title>
  <style>
    /* Initially hide the div */
    #showDiv {
      display: none;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #252525;
      color: #ffffff;
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- The checkbox and the div to toggle -->
  <form>
    <input class="input" type="checkbox" id="checkbox-id"> Toggle Div
  </form>
  <div id="showDiv">Show / hide</div>

  <script>
    // Get the checkbox element
    const check = document.getElementById("checkbox-id");
    if (check) {
      // Add a single click event listener
      check.addEventListener('click', () => {
        // Get the div to show/hide
        const showDiv = document.getElementById("showDiv");

        // Toggle visibility based on checkbox state
        if (check.checked) {
          showDiv.style.display = "block"; // Show the div
        } else {
          showDiv.style.display = "none"; // Hide the div
        }
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>



Why This Works:
The single addEventListener('click') handles both showing and hiding the div by checking the state of the checkbox (checked property).
This approach is simple, avoids redundancy, and works in any JavaScript environment.

Thank you for your time and this clean solution. Unfortunately, it has the same effect. Unchecking the box does not remove the div in my filter. I've ultimately added a separate close button to the div until I can test this solution further. Not ideal but it does allow the box to close.
